# react-native-localize: change language of ALL screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in my react-native app I'm using react-native-localize to localize my app.

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-localize

I change app locale like this:

```
I18n.locale = newLocale
```

This works only for the active screen, if I navigate back to previous screens they are still using the old locale language...

How I localize my strings in components:

```
import I18n from "@utils/i18n";

<Text style={{ fontSize:18, color:'black'}}>{I18n.t(item.title)}</Text>
```

How I setup I18n, I import this file in all the screens I use I18n, could this be the cause the locale keeps resetting to first locale in previous screens:

```
//utils/i18n
import I18n from "i18n-js";
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

import en from "@locales/en";
import es from "@locales/es";

const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();

if (Array.isArray(locales)) {
  I18n.locale = locales[0].languageTag;
}

I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  es
};


export default I18n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to re-rerender the whole app.

You can do it either by listening to the store property such as "currentLanguage" in the top component of your app (often called rootNavigator / rootComponent), or e.g. by introducing the React context and changing its values with each localization change.

Comment: I also wrote a blog post about the whole process: 
https://stefan-majiros.com/blog/implementing-react-native-localization-like-a-pro/